# Ошибка на Django: list index out of range

Tags: python, django

Есть парсер, который получает список подписчиков из инстаграм. В коде парсера есть такая строчка: `user = str(urlopen(i.href).read(),"utf-8")`. На локалке всё работает нормально, а на сайте стало выдавать ошибку:

```
"/home/django/django_venv/src/index/views.py" in search_akk
  1147.                 user_id = re.findall(r"\"id\":\"(\d+)\",",user,re.MULTILINE)[0]

Exception Type: IndexError at /search_akk/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

Вместо json срока - `user = str(urlopen(i.href).read(),"utf-8")` стала выдавать html. Раньше все работало нормально и выдавало json. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте узнать, какой именно html возвращает сервер. Вероятно, он возвращает страницу с ошибкой.

Comment: Html страницы входа - Login.